# I want to start a symbian application development..what are the basic requirements for creating symbian apps?

Tags: symbian, nokia

I want to start a symbian application development..what are the basic requirements for creating symbian apps?

I have downloaded Eclipse JUNO 221 mb
what other plugins required?

Comment: May be this can help you to start:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541613/how-to-get-started-with-symbian-s60-plattorm

Comment: Check out also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769223/rapid-application-development-for-nokia-e5-symbian-s60-v3/